# Extends an abstract class and use it in sub class while keeping types

Tags: typescript

I need to create an abstract class with protected members, and keep the typing of elements

I tried with an abstract class, I can have protected members but I can't keep the type defined in this abstract class in sub class

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ehyynu?file=testImplement.ts

I tried with an interface, I can't have protected members but I have the types

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ja9fqr?file=testInterface.ts,testImplement.ts

Do I misse something, Is there a way to have protected members and typing ?

Comment: Well, `(): boolean => { return true;  };` is assignable to `(test: string) => void;`. Like,
`let test: (test: string) => void = (): boolean => { return true; };` is valid TypeScript. The typing is still there, you cannot override with `protectedMethod = (a: number, b:number): boolean => {return true;}`, for example.

Comment: Didn't saw this, thanks a lot !